# Backup SQL Server 2019 in a Docker Linux container fails

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms, sqlcmd, azure-data-studio

Attempted multiple ways to do the backup.

Tried adding SA as a root user in the container

***Azure Data studio***

```
BACKUP DATABASE [PrestigeCars] TO  DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup//PrestigeCars-202044-8-4-52.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'PrestigeCars--2020-04-04T12:04:52', NOSKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
>   Cannot open backup device '/var/opt/mssql/backup//PrestigeCars-202044-8-4-52.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.). 
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. 
>   Total execution time: 00:00:00.217

***SSMS***

```
backup database [PrestigeCars]
to  disk = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup//PrestigeCars-202044-6-42-9.bak'
with noformat
    , noinit
    , name = N'PrestigeCars--20200404'
    , noskip
    , rewind
    , nounload
    , compression
    , stats = 10;
```

***SQLCMD***

```
sqlcmd -S localhost,12001 -U SA -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [PrestigeCars] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/CSCI331-Backup/PrestigeCars-202044-6-42-9.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'PrestigeCars-20200404', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Look at your file path: `backup//PrestigeCars` Notice the **two** `/` characters.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of those of you that have helped.  The issue was not missing folders but a permissions issue.

The folders were initially create when copying backups to the container:

***docker cp /Users/YourUsername/CSCI331-Backup/TSQLV4.bak linux-sql2k19:/var/opt/mssql/backup/***

***The permissions were 4 drwxr-xr-**x** 3 root  root 4096 Jan 31 19:06 backup***

I tried various Ubuntu create sudo adduser but none of the commands sudo or apt-get worked. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

**I found this command to connect as the root user**

***docker exec -it -u root 874 bash***

cd /var/opt/mssql/backup/

cd ..

chmod 777 backup

cd ..

chmod 777 mssql

cd ..

chmod 777 opt

cd ..

chmod 777 var

**Close the container. I backed up databases in SSMS and Azure Data Studio. Double Yeah!**

Answer (score 0):

Directory `/var/opt/mssql/backup` does not exist in standard SQL Server Linux images. You'll need to first create the directory by running the following command in the container:

```
mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup
```

Also, as @Larnu pointed out, you have an extra backslash in the path. The backup command should be:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [PrestigeCars] TO  DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/PrestigeCars-202044-8-4-52.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'PrestigeCars--2020-04-04T12:04:52', NOSKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10;
```

Comment: @Larnu, the default user is `mssql` with `docker exec -it sql-container-name bash`. So the `mkdir` command creates the directory with `drwxr-xr-x`, same as the other sql directories.

Comment: Fair enough, I've personally not used `docker` for SQL Server, just actual Linux installs and LXD, so wasn't sure and why I made the comment.

Comment: First, the directory does exist.  It was created using a docker copy

Comment: @PeterH, so did the backup work once you removed the extraneous slash?